# windows environment variable not visible in eclipse ant target

Tags: eclipse, ant, environment-variables

I have an ant task that set environment variables by calling the setenv.bat file:

```
<target name="setEnvWindows" if="isWindows" >
    <exec dir="C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_OSB1\tools\configjar" executable="cmd">
        <arg value="/c"/>
        <arg value="setenv.bat"/>
    </exec>
    <echo message="SetEnvWindows"/>
</target>
```

Next I have another task that uses these variables:

```
<property environment="env"/>
<echo message="${env.OSB_HOME}"/>
```

However the variable set in the first target : OSB_HOME is not visible for the remaining targets. It becomes visible only after restarting eclipse.

How can I define the environment variable such that they are visible for subsequent targets without restarting eclipse?

Comment: why do you want to set windows env variables and use it further in your build?, instead you can create some custom property in your build and use those

Comment: I agree with the first comment, if you want to use those values in the same build do you have to use environment variables?

Comment: The reason is the reuse of existing resources. In order to export an OSB project, I need to run only once setenv.bat, then I have to run the task that builds the jar. I'm trying to automate the process by executing the two tasks from an ant script.